# Despliegue a heroku node js

Tags: nodejs, base-de-datos, heroku

tengo un problema y es el siguiente desplegué mi aplicación de nodejs en heroku pero al momento de revisar los logs porque no estaba arriba me arroja este error.

```
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:101:31)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:313:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
at Connection._notifyError (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:236:12)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:107:12)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:313:12) {
fatal: true,
code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
}
```

Lo único que entiendo de esto es que algo esta pasando con la conexión a la base de datos, no se si tal vez alguien me pueda ayudar si necesitan el código me dicen y lo paso

Comment: Heroku no es un servidor privado, para conectar tu bd necesitar contratarla dentro de heroku o usar un servidor externo. Como lo estas haciendo?

Comment: Estoy habilitando una base de datos mysql y con la url que me arroja de conexión, es con la que configuro mi aplicación.